# SoapUI JSONPath Match assertion: How to reference a parameter of the REST request

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I'm trying to write a JSONPath Match assertion for a test step in a test case in my REST project. This test step is a REST request. The response is a JSON string. Referencing the response's nodes is not a problem (in this instance I use '$..startDate').

However, for the "Expected Result" portion of this assertion, I need to reference one of the parameters of my **request**. This parameter is called 'date', and in the assertion I want to check if the 'startDate' node of my Json response matches 'date'.

I would have thought that something like `${#TestCase#["Start Date GET Request"]#Request#date}` would work, but it doesn't. When I test the assertion I'm told that the result for it is empty (i.e. "[]")

I tried several variations of the above.

`${#Project#TestSuite#TestCase#["Start Date GET Request"]#Request#date}`

`${#["Start Date GET Request"]#Request#date}`

`${#["Start Date GET Request"]#date}`

The result is always the same.

Any advice on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation for expected result using JSONPath must be:

`${RESTRequestName#Response#$.json.path.to.date}`

Use the exactly name of your testStep (without `#` this is used for `#TestCase`, `#TestSuite` when you want to refer a property at this level, but not for properties at testStep level.

To work with the response passing a JSONPath use the `$.` to start your path.

**EDIT**

I misunderstand your question, if you simply want the `query` parameter `date` use the follow notation:

`${RESTRequestName#date}`

As explained above, use the testStep name without `#` and then since SOAPUI adds all query parameters as properties of the testStep you can access directly using it's name like you can do with `Request`,`Response`, and so on.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I think there is a misunderstanding. The parameter I want to reference is not in the Response. It is a parameter of the type "Query" that I send with the request. Referencing the nodes in the response using JSONPath is not a problem.

Comment: @E.T. nice to help you `:)`